# How to match only the one word tag without the multiple word tag in image-dired?

Tags: regular-expressions, tags, image-dired

In [image-dired](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Image_002dDired.html) I use `M-x` `image-dired-mark-tagged-files` to mark files containing a tag e.g. `bar` (one word tag). **The problem** is that `foo bar` (multiple word tag) is marked as well.

What regex do I need to mark the tag `bar` but *not* the other tag `foo bar`?

Input ([how image-dired stores files](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/image-dired.el#L56)):

```
/foo/IMG_2022.JPG;foo bar
/foo/IMG_2023.JPG;bar
```

Expected match

```
/foo/IMG_2023.JPG;bar
```

Answer (score 1):

Please <kbd>M-x</kbd> `report-emacs-bug`

The current implementation (as of 28.1) of `image-dired-mark-tagged-files` doesn't make it possible to reliably isolate a tag:

```el
(image-dired--with-db-file
 ;; Collect matches
 (while (search-forward-regexp
         (concat "\\(^[^;\n]+\\);.*" tag ".*$") nil t)
   (push (match-string 1) files)))
```

You can isolate the *end* of a tag using `bar\(;\|$\)` and if there's a *preceding* tag you can then use `;bar\(;\|$\)` -- but if there's no preceding tag then you can't do anything about that `.*` before the tag resulting in a match for `foobar`, so I'd treat this as a bug.

Comment: Fixed for Emacs 29.  https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=a9d226dea4d0cc190ab6d9dcc430e94b41115fc4

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

#### `M-x re-builder` with `C-c TAB rx RET`

[image: Buffer with *RE-Builder*]

#### `rx`-form of the regexp

```
 '(and ";"
       ;; Match the tags that precede "bar"
       (group                ; This only to give it some color
    (optional
     (one-or-more (not (or ";" "\n"))) ; one or more tags, together with it's separator
     (one-or-more " ")         ; separator
     ))
       ;; Match the tag itself
       (group                ; This only to give it some color
    "bar")
       ;; Match the tags that follows "bar"
       (group                ; This only to give it some color
    (optional
     (and
      (one-or-more " ")     ; separator
      (zero-or-more (not (or ";" "\n"))) ; one or more tags, together with it's separator
      )))
       line-end)
```

#### Convert `rx`-form to `string` and `read`-formats

```
*** Welcome to IELM ***  Type (describe-mode) or press C-h m for help.
ELISP> (rx-to-string 
 '(and ";"
       ;; Match the tags that precede "bar"
       (group                ; This only to give it some color
    (optional
     (one-or-more (not (or ";" "\n"))) ; one or more tags, together with it's separator
     (one-or-more " ")         ; separator
     ))
       ;; Match the tag itself
       (group                ; This only to give it some color
    "bar")
       ;; Match the tags that follows "bar"
       (group                ; This only to give it some color
    (optional
     (and
      (one-or-more " ")     ; separator
      (zero-or-more (not (or ";" "\n"))) ; one or more tags, together with it's separator
      )))
       line-end)
)
"\\(?:;\\(\\(?:[^
;]+ +\\)?\\)\\(bar\\)\\(\\(?: +[^
;]*\\)?\\)$\\)"
ELISP> (message "%s" *)
"\\(?:;\\(\\(?:[^
;]+ +\\)?\\)\\(bar\\)\\(\\(?: +[^
;]*\\)?\\)$\\)"
ELISP>
```

#### Regex for use with `minibuffer` format

If you are `C-u C-s`-ing then you can use type the following---which is what you would see in `*Messages*` buffer---at minibuffer prompt

```
\(?:;\(\(?:[^
;]+ +\)?\)\(bar\)\(\(?: +[^
;]*\)?\)$\)
```

#### `C-u C-s`in action

[image: Input forC-u C-s]

*(Of course, I could have used `C-c TAB` in in the `"*RE-Builder*"` buffer to effect the conversion from `rx`->`read`->`string` formats.)*

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Bookmark+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) then you can [tag](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#BookmarkTags) files with *arbitrary* strings, including strings containing whitespace.

There are commands for accessing files with tags all of which, or some of which, match a given regexp. The matching is against each tag separately, so there's no problem such as you report for image-dired tags.

For example, command `bmkp-autofile-all-tags-regexp-jump`, bound by default to `C-x j t a % *`:

> **`bmkp-autofile-all-tags-regexp-jump`** is an interactive compiled Lisp
> function in [`bookmark+-1.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/bookmark%2b-1.el).
>
> `(bmkp-autofile-all-tags-regexp-jump REGEXP BOOKMARK)`
>
> Jump to an autofile `BOOKMARK` in this dir that *has each tag matching* `REGEXP`.
>
> You are prompted for the `REGEXP`.
>
> Then you are prompted for the `BOOKMARK` (with completion).

Bookmark+ commands pertaining to tags are by default on prefix key **`C-x x t`** — use `C-x x t C-h` to see them.

And the keys on that prefix by default follow a mnemonic pattern. For example the key sequence `C-x j t a % *` uses these mnemonics:

- **`j`** means it's a bookmark **j**ump command (visit the bookmarked file)
- **`t`** means it's a **t**ags command
- **`a`** means it's an **a**utofile command, that is, the bookmark is an [**autofile**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#AutofileBookmarks): a file wrapper, and its name is the file name
- **`%`** means that the command prompts for a *regexp* (to match tags)

In the bookmark list (buffer `*Bookmark List*`), commands pertaining to tags are on prefix key **`T`** — use `T C-h` to see them.  For example, you can [mark](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#TagCommandsAndKeys) and unmark the bookmarks that have tags matching various patterns.

Answer (score 0):

#### Using `rx-let` to build a regular expression brick-by-brick

See [Defining new rx forms](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Extending-Rx.html)

```lisp
(info "(elisp) Extending Rx")
```

This  ...

```lisp
(require 'rx)
(rx-let (
     (tags-start (seq ";" (zero-or-more " ")))
     (tags-end (seq (zero-or-more " ") line-end))
     (tag-separators (one-or-more " "))
     (tag (one-or-more (not (or " " ";" "\n" "\r"))))
     (leading-tags (zero-or-more (seq tag tag-separators)))
     (lagging-tags (zero-or-more (seq tag-separators tag)))
     (match-this-tag (tag)
             (seq tags-start leading-tags tag lagging-tags tags-end)))
  (rx (match-this-tag "bar")))
```

on evaluation gives

```lisp
"; *\\(?:[^

 ;]+ +\\)*bar\\(?: +[^

 ;]+\\)* *$"
```

The above value can then be plugged in to a `*RE-Builder*` that uses `string` format